# Setting div height after using z-index propriety

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

How to remove padding from div after replacing another div using z-index propriety.

This is basic HTML structure:
a) main container, `height:auto`
b) div that should be overflowed
c) div that overflows div b)

After moving c) div up for 200px, I get empty space. Main container has auto height propriety, but it remains the same size.
My question is how do you guys remove extra space after moving divs up with position/z-index proprieties

Comment: Could you post the code and/or and example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NqphG/ My question is, how should I make the red div to change its size, because now it is empty space after moving green div up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative margin instead of positioning div#c. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NqphG/4/).

A negative margin doesn't alter the stacking but is able to put the div#c over div#b. Don't forget the phenomenon of the [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

In some cases, you can arrive at the same conclustion as far as the painting is concerned  (doesn't matter what techinque you take). But the route leads along important css concepts:

- By means of top|right|bottom|left an offset is carried out **after** div#c has taken up room. Therefore, a following element (or in your case: div#a) is arranged in such a way so if it were not first been positioned.
- positioning can create a new stacking context (in conjunction with a z-index != auto)
- an element that is positioned relative creates a containing block (a frame of reference for descendants that are positioned absolute)
- Relative positioning is more or less consciously used as a bugfix for IE.

Answer (score 0):

try this replace top:-30px; with margin-top:-30px;

http://jsfiddle.net/NqphG/1/